# email alert in workflow - sender's name in salutation in sent mail instead of recipient

Tags: email, workflow, salesforce, alert, visualforce

I have setup a custome object (Test WF) with default "Owner" and custom "Status" field. My aim is to trigger mail whenever "status" field is "Assigned", hence setup workflow rule with rule "Test WF: Status equals Assigned" and included email alert in immediate action on workflow. Below is the visualforce email template I am using.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="WF EMail Test" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Test_WF__c">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >

Dear {!recipient.Name},

</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Now if a user "Person 1" is creating the "Test WF" record, owner will be set to "Person 1". After this if "Person 2" will change the status field to "Assigned", an email will be triggered to "Person 1" like below.

Dear Person 2,

"Person 1" is getting this email containing text "Dear Person 2".
Please note "to" and "from" email addresses are correct.
I am facing issue here, why I am getting "Person 2" in the solutation even though it is sent to "Person 1" from "Person 2"?

Please help!!

Comment: For quick resolution, please post it here : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

This is official Salesforce SE portal now.

Comment: thanks Abhinav, appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

Start creating a new (plaintext) email template, then play with the merge field dropdowns.

```
"Sending User fields" -> {!User.Name} etc.
"Receiving User fields" -> {!Receiving_User.Name}
```

You should be able to use these in VF email template too, not only plaintext/html/letterhead ones.

There's even more fun when you're making an email to be used in approval process, you can have to use {!ApprovalRequest.Process_Assignee} etc ;)

Experiment and make sure it works as expected before you'll deploy. Unmatched merge fields will be simply blank.